# This page isn’t working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405

Tags: php, html, post, get, http-status-code-405

It is showing this error in console: This page isn’t working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405

Header shows this
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:5501/Assignment%202%20-%20Web%20development/submit.php
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address:
127.0.0.1:5501
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Here is my code that I've been trying

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>XYZ Workshop Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>XYZ Workshop Registration</h1>
        <form id="registration-form" method="POST" action="submit.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fullname">Full Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
                <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

submit.php

```
<?php
// Check if the form is submitted via POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Check if all required fields are set
    if(isset($_POST['fullname']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone'])) {
        // Collect form data
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];

        // Perform validation (you can add more validation if needed)

        // Connect to your database (replace with your database credentials)
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "your_username";
        $password = "your_password";
        $dbname = "your_database_name";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        // Prepare SQL statement to insert data into the database (replace with your table name and column names)
        $sql = "INSERT INTO participants (fullname, email, phone) VALUES ('$fullname', '$email', '$phone')";

        // Execute SQL statement
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        // Close database connection
        $conn->close();
    } else {
        echo "All fields are required";
    }
}

// Check if GET request is made
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    // Perform actions based on parameters passed in the URL
    // For example, you can retrieve data from the database and return it
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        // Fetch data based on the ID passed in the URL
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        
        // Connect to the database and retrieve data
        // Replace this with your own logic to fetch data
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "your_username";
        $password = "your_password";
        $dbname = "your_database_name";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        // Prepare SQL statement to fetch data from the database
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM participants WHERE id = $id";

        // Execute SQL statement
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        // Check if data is retrieved
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // Output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "Full Name: " . $row["fullname"]. " - Email: " . $row["email"]. " - Phone: " . $row["phone"]. "<br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "No results found";
        }

        // Close database connection
        $conn->close();
    } else {
        echo "ID parameter is required";
    }
}
?>
```

Can anyone help to solve this problem? Like where am I wrong?

Comment: Turn on error reporting at the top of your submit.php script. In this way you can see the underlying PHP error

Comment: @GetSet it's not getting as far as PHP

Comment: Make sure 1) you're using a proper webserver (not VS Code Live Server or anything like that) and accessing the files via `http://localhost` (assuming you're testing this on your local machine), 2) that your webserver has PHP installed in it, and 3) your file is named with a `.php` extension. This error often occurs when you're using a basic webserver which only supports GET requests to static files.